# why must I use sometimes screen -rx and not screen -r?

Tags: linux, debian, gnu-screen

Sometimes to get access to screen console I need to user `screen -rx` and not just `screen -r`.

Any idea why and why this happens ?

Answer (score 3):

`-x` attaches to an already running screen. Two or more terminals can share one session.

`-r` restores a detached session

Most probably you have to use `-x` when a session was not cleanly disconnected and is still considered running. The `-xr` is unnecessary in that case.

Answer (score 2):

`screen -rx` attaches to a session that is already attached elsewhere, and allows simultaneous use of the screen session by all attached parties.

In the event that a `screen -r` fails with something similar to:

```
There is a screen on:
    10250.ttys016.ironforge (Attached)
There is no screen to be resumed.
```

... you can use `screen -rd` to force the other party to detach & allow you to attach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `-x` if you want to attach to an already running screen without detaching the other sessions.

If the session hasn't disconnected cleanly, you have other options than `-x`:

- `-d` does the same than typing C-A d from the controlling terminal for the session.
- `-D` is the equivalent to the power detach key. (Both `-d` &`-D` are ignored, when not applicable.)
- Both of the above work in combination with `-r` *resume* and `-R` *resume first appropriate*.
- A powerful & useful combination is `-D -R` for *attach here and now*.
- For all combinations, see [screen manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) for command-line option `-d`.